# There are some warnings when I sent cn1 android build to google play

Tags: codenameone

This question is for codenameone.

androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Consider upgrading to a newer version (1.0.1 - 1.0.2, 1.1.0-alpha02+).

Comment: The message is clear enough. What is your question?

Comment: Can you look through the build hints and see if this dependency or something similar is mentioned there? If not please include the android build hints that might be related in the question.

Comment: Someone always asks for closing my question related to the build issue related to cn1.
Is there any better way to report the cn1 build issue?

Comment: I attached the android build hint to the question.

Comment: I need the values for these hints too. You can file [issues](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) assuming there isn't one already. You can also use the [reddit group](https://reddit.com/r/cn1/).

Comment: How do I send you the value?

Comment: You can edit the question and include both ideally in plain text in which case you can remove the private information. This will be helpful as it's easier to read than a screenshot.  If you can't do that and are concerned with private information then send it in the chat support on the website.

Comment: I sent the file in the chat on cn1 website.

Comment: Got it. I don't see anything specific. Checking with Steve

Answer (score 0):

Steve added a build hint `androidx.appcompat.version` that will allow you to play with different values for the `appcompat` library. We aren't sure this is the right thing, but it's the only thing in the dependency tree that has a 1.0.0, and is remotely related to the error.

This maven central page shows possible version numbers that you can try:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat

Comment: I add a build hint androidx.appcompat.version and set the value to 1.6.1. in settings.
Sending android build to cn1 server but get the error below: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /home/ec2-user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-
I also sent the error to chat on cn1 website.

Comment: Maybe try a more conservative value like `1.0.2`?

Comment: I set the build hint androidx.appcompat.version with 1.0.2. I got the same warning message from google play. upgrading to a newer version (1.0.1 - 1.0.2, 1.1.0-alpha02+)

Comment: Then I guess it's probably not the cause. We will need to dig deeper into this.

Answer (score 0):

"Android resource linking failed" Error is usually due incompatibility between **Android Gradle version** and **gradle dependencies**. See [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/xy1ep8/android_build_with_android_archive_aar_library/?onetap_auto=true)

In this case seems androidx.appcompat.version version you are setting is not compatible with gradle version used.

FYI I builds using gradle version 7.5.1 & gradle classpath 4.2.2 and there are no such warnings when publishing to playstore.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
```

I also builds using these gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    //implement material design support used in API level 29+
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    //support multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Push notification
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

    //Rooted device check
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.8'

    //test deps
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**NOTE:** building using a newer gradle version like 7.5.1 allows you to comfortably use up to date dependencies like above without having to worry about compatibility issues.