# Upgrade to a newer com.google.android.gms SDK version - Codename One

Tags: android, google-play, codenameone, netbeans-8

I am trying to publish a Codename One app bundle in play store and I cant because they are giving me this error.

"The developer of Maps SDK for Android (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps) has reported version 12.0.1 as outdated. After 90 days from releasing this version of your app, you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK until you upgrade to a newer version (17.0.0+)."

I have checked some other apps that I had already published into the Play Console and found this message.

"The SDK developer com.google.android.gms has reported play-services-maps:12.0.1 as outdated. If you do not upgrade to a newer version, you may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK."[image]

Comment: Is this a server build or a local build? Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399890/there-are-some-warnings-when-i-sent-cn1-android-build-to-google-play/76440838#76440838)

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed this issue somehow. I guess it wasn't tagged with `codenameone` initially. This is discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/18occij/codenameone_problems_with_sdk/). The gist is to just add the build hint `android.useGradle8=true`.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you need to update the Maps SDK. You can try using the latest version before uploading the build to PlayConsole. You can refer the below URl for the latest version.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#console_1